# Get Available time slot MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

At this moment, I could query all the booked time of a hall as follows:

```
SELECT TM.id
     , TM.start_date as start
     , TM.end_date as end
     , TM.start_time as start_time
     , TM.end_time as end_time
     , T.space 
  FROM times as T 
  JOIN times_meta as TM 
    ON T.id = TM.time_id 
 WHERE T.hall_id = 1 
   AND TM.start_date = "2019-09-20" 
 order 
    by start_time asc;
```

And this return result as:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| id  | start      | end        | start_time | end_time | space  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+----------+--------|
|  12 | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 07:00:00   | 10:00:00 | full   |
|  2  | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 10:00:00   | 11:00:00 | full   |
|  13 | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 13:00:00   | 17:00:00 | full   |
|  15 | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 17:00:00   | 18:00:00 | half   |
|  14 | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 18:00:00   | 19:00:00 | full   |
|  16 | 2012-09-20 | 2012-09-20 | 19:00:00   | 21:00:00 | shared |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+
```

For this let's say the business hours is from `07:00:00` to `21:00:00`.

This means the available time frame is `11-13`, `17-18` and `19-21`. It's because if the space is `full` means the time-slot could not be shared. And for `half` it could be shared between two parties and for `shared` this could be shared up to 4 parties.

Table (times)

```
id, space, hall_id
```

Table (times_meta)

```
id, start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time, time_id
//time_id is foreign key from times table
```

I think this might be little complicate with MySql alone, so its totally fine to get the desired result with the help of php code.

All I want is to get the list of available time frame such as:
Available

```
11:00:00 - 13:00:00 - full
17:00:00 - 18:00:00 - half
19:00:00 - 21:00:00 - half / shared
```

### Update:

SQL to create schema:

```
CREATE TABLE times (
id integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
space tinyint NOT NULL COMMENT ' 4 - full, 2 - half, 1 -shared ',
hall_id INT(6) UNSIGNED
);

CREATE TABLE times_meta (
id integer UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
start_date date NOT NULL,
end_date date NOT NULL,
start_time time NOT NULL,
end_time time NOT NULL,
time_id INT(6) UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (time_id) REFERENCES times(id)
);

INSERT INTO times 
        (name, space, hall_id)
VALUES 
        ('Booked by User 1', '4', '1'),
        ('Booked by User 2', '4', '1'),
        ('Booked by User 3', '4', '1'),
        ('Booked by User 4', '2', '1'),
        ('Booked by User 5', '4', '1'),
        ('Booked by User 5', '1', '1');

INSERT INTO times_meta 
        (start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time, time_id)
VALUES
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '07:00:00', '10:00:00', '1'),
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '2'),
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '13:00:00', '17:00:00', '3'),
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '17:00:00', '18:00:00', '4'),
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '18:00:00', '19:00:00', '5'),
        ('2019-09-20', '2019-09-20', '19:00:00', '21:00:00', '6');
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12aa5e)

Comment: @Strawberry I  have tried to create a similar database with the possible datasets. I don't know about sqlfiddle either it will be same on you side or not. So, I have provided the tested code, its should genereate a minimal data sets. Now, could you please help me on this. If any further information is required, please, let me know. Thank you for being nice. There are many persons on stackoverflow, who just downvote and runaway, without mentioning the reason, if incase full required infromations are not provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So i was trying to achieve the result and i got a solution with mixed php and mysql.
I used mysql to get all the list of rooms that are available as half or shared and php is used to get full availability of rooms.
In php the idea is to first store all the start and end time of meeting in two separate arrays and if start time of next meeting is not equal to end time of this meeting then we have a available time slot between them.
I have created start and end array statically now for example.

To get all Full lists

```
<?php

$start = array('07:00:00','10:00:00','13:00:00','17:00:00','18:00:00','19:00:00');
$end = array('10:00:00','11:00:00','17:00:00','18:00:00','19:00:00','21:00:00');
$arrlength = count($start);
for($x = 1; $x < $arrlength-1; $x++) {
    if($start[$x]!=$end[$x-1]){
        echo $end[$x-1]."-".$start[$x]." - "."Full";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

For Half/Shared rooms

```
SELECT 
   TM.start_time as start_time
 , TM.end_time as end_time
 ,
CASE 
    WHEN T.space = 2 THEN 'Half'
    WHEN T.space = 1 THEN 'Half/Shared'
END AS 'TYPE'
  FROM times as T 
  JOIN times_meta as TM 
    ON T.id = TM.time_id 
 WHERE T.hall_id = 1 
   AND TM.start_date = "2019-09-20"
   AND T.space != 4
 order 
    by start_time asc;
```